# Matplotlib not animating azimuth unless I click on the plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to animate the point of view of a scatter plot, that is coming from a sequence of data arrays. I am currently stuck because the animation runs only if I keep clicking on the plot. It seems to animate in the background with correct timing but only displaying when I click on it.

I tried other animation examples and they were ok, so I guess there must be some problem with my code. Thanks for the help.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

data = [np.random.random_sample((300, 3)) for _ in range(10)]
x, y, z = data[0][:, 0], data[0][:, 1], data[0][:, 2]


def update_pov(num):
    ax.view_init(elev=10., azim=num % 360)
    
    return graph,


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")
graph = ax.scatter(x, y, z, color='orange')

ax.set_xlim3d(0, 1)
ax.set_ylim3d(0, 1)
ax.set_zlim3d(0, 1)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_pov, frames=200, interval=50, blit=False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I can reproduce this. If I save the animation to a gif by running `ani.save("tmp.gif")`, the gif seems to be animated correctly. This may be a matplotlib bug. You might want to report this to https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues

Comment: good point! I did not try to save it to data. For now I am using cla() and recreating the scatter at every frame. This solves it.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem. matplotlib 3.5.1.

Comment: it might be platform specific, I am on a Macair arm, matplotlib also 3.5.1

Comment: filed as a bug for anyone interested https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/22598